# WARNING: No target specified, deploying to device '' even though --target is specified

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, deployment

I know this question has been asked a thousand times but I find myself in a situation I cannot quite explain.

I get `No target specified, deploying to device '0123456789ABCDEF'` even though I specified the target with the switch `--target` with the below command.

`ionic cordova run android --target:0123456789ABCDEF` [image: Deployment Command]

But I get the following:

`No target specified, deploying to device '0123456789ABCDEF'` [image: warinng message]

I even tried to add the `--device:0123456789ABCDEF` switch as well but all the same.

How can I actually make it deploy correctly?

In addition, if I have 2 android devices deployed, it mostly deploys to the other device instead. To work around this, I usually unplug the second device, then plug it again when deployment is done.

Comment: Try `ionic cordova run android --target=0123456789ABCDEF`

Comment: Make that into an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [CLI docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/) example you need to use `=` to give the value and not `:`.

Use:

```
ionic cordova run android --target=0123456789ABCDEF
```